# numpy is not installing in windows 7 soon after get-pip.py

Tags: python-2.7

[image]

This is the error  please  help me what to do 
i have downloaded  all the dependencies  but numpy is showing errors

Comment: do you have a stable internet connection?

Comment: Please post the error as text.

Answer (score 0):

you're using pip3 - that's for Python3.

Try `pip install numpy`